# Kotlin Multiplatform Mobile How to navigate between screens using single codebase

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I cannot find any library or any supporting doc to switch between screens in KMM for ios and android.

I researched and also tried implementing navgraph but it is for android only and there is nothing i can find similar to the nav for ios.

Comment: Well i found something and am currently using this library known as PreCompose [link](https://github.com/Tlaster/PreCompose)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Voyager](https://voyager.adriel.cafe/) A multiplatform navigation library.
Supported Platform: Android, iOS, Desktop, Web

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called routing. And almost any "architecture" lib provides that. The most popular is [Decompose](https://github.com/arkivanov/Decompose)

https://github.com/AAkira/Kotlin-Multiplatform-Libraries#architecture

Answer (score 0):

Here you can read the official documentation about [navigation](https://arkivanov.github.io/Decompose/navigation/overview/) of decompose. I recommend to read all the documentation because it also can function as a shared viewmodel with reactive state management.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).